# How to add a column alias into yii active record model?

Tags: activerecord, primary-key, column-alias

In my old project I used *long* id for table primary key, like 'shop_id' or 'order_id', but now I want to use just 'id' as alias for 'shop_id'. How to add this to the model class only, not changing tables. After that I'd like to have something like this

```
$model->id = $var
```

or

```
$var = $model->id
```

and

```
$var = $model->attributes['id'].
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a getter method in your model code like this:

```
public function getId(){
   return $this->shop_id
}
```

If you have this on many tables, you could extend CActiveRecord and add a getter to that class like this:

```
public function getId(){
    return $this->{$this->tableSchema->primaryKey};
}
```

Comment: No, I did this, of course. But in this case we can just get or set data -  $model->alias_column. But !! what about find() methods? I see we have to overload some CActiveFider methods /related to schema/

Comment: Ahh, I see - that isn't the question you asked however, you asked how to use a non table variable in this form: `$var = $model->id`. You would have to overload quite a lot of methods in Yii to accomplish this, as there isn't a single place that builds queries - it is quite a convoluted process.

Comment: Thanks, I see that the best way is to use PostgreSQL database capabilities (rule system).